# Fullcalendar populate event after selecting date

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using [fullcalendar v4](https://fullcalendar.io/#demos). In the demo i see how we select date and it is updating event. I want the same. However I couldn't get any method to update event. I tried to [feed event as function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function), but I dont't see it being trigger when I select date.

```
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'  ],

      header: {
        left: 'today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek'
      },
    defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror:true,
    selectOverlap: true,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    select: function(selectionInfo){
        console.log(selectionInfo)
    },
    events: 
    events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        console.log({info}, {successCallback}, {failureCallback});
    }
    ,

    });
    calendar.render();
```

Comment: " I tried to feed event as function" ...did you? Please show your attempt then, so that we can understand exactly what you did. The example above uses a static data array.

Comment: Also "i see how we select date and it is updating event." ...are you talking about dragging and dropping the event onto a new date? That is a separate process from providing the events as a feed. Please can you be a bit clearer about exactly what the issue is. Are you asking how to send information about the newly updated event back to your server?

Comment: Or are you talking about "selecting a date" as in selecting a new area of the calendar on which to create a new event? Again this is a separate process from the feed of events coming back.

Comment: Hi @ADyson I have given the demo link. I want exactly same. I select date range from start date to end date and I want to open a popup to populate event data and push to the event. I have updated my question with what I have tried with even feed as a function

Comment: ok. This has nothing to do with the event feed. If you go to the date selection demo page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo you can follow the link to the CodePen page and then see how it's implemented. And it's up to you to decide how you want to implement saving that new event to your server, if that's a requirement.

Comment: The demo link you send me I have already reached there. Now I would like to update the selected event in event feed.

Comment: Now, assuming that, in a real-world application, your event feed data would actually come from a server, the way to "update the event feed" would actually be to send an AJAX request to your server containing the data of the new event. The server would then add it to your database. Then, next time someone loads your calendar, the server would provide that new event data inside the JSON it creates for fullCalendar.

Comment: That link doesnt show any event. Please see the demo link in my question. I hope you will understand I am looking for.

Comment: Please forget about real world application :) Can you help me with just the demo link I shared in the question. I just need that. I will take care the rest of the server side things.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of a different demo. You can use [addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) to add the data to the calendar instantly. If you spend a few moments looking at the documentation page you can see it easily. And then of course you could also send the data to your server at the same time via AJAX. Wanting to add it to the event feed data directly doesn't actually make a lot of sense in reality. In reality the event feed data is never just an array in your page.